# SD card full bricks Android 2.2: In fsckdelay end. Kill dosfsck, ret=-1

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sd-card, file-system, unbricking, zip

I downloaded [this 80 MB ZIP file containing 27000 files](http://oxygenguide.googlecode.com/files/OxygenGuide_2013-01-12-a.zip) to my SD card and unzipped it using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6728732/226958).
A no space left error occurred before all files could be extracted.

I couldn't remove the folder, neither with `adb shell rm -f` nor the Open Manager app nor by mounting the SD card and removing from Ubuntu/Nautilus:

```
$ adb shell rm -f /sdcard/OxygenGuide
rm failed for /sdcard/OxygenGuide, I/O error
```

Ubuntu/Nautilus:

```
There was an error deleting 08267130495190304.html.
Error removing file: Read-only file system
```

It looked like trying to remove this particular file makes the whole SD card read-only.
Unmounting/remounting made it read/write again, but the same error happened when I tried to delete again.

---

I decided to reboot, and now I just have a black screen with just the top bar, showing the "Checking SD card" icon and usual network/battery/date. `adb logcat` shows this:

```
I/ActivityThread(  323): Publishing provider downloads: com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider
W/Vold    (   71): Filesystem modified - rechecking (pass 2)
I/Vold    (   71): Device /dev/block/vold/179:1, target /mnt/sdcard mounted @ /mnt/secure/staging
D/Vold    (   71): Volume sdcard state changing 3 (Checking) -> 4 (Mounted)
I/ActivityThread(  270): Publishing provider call_log: com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider
W/logwrapper(   71): In fsckdelay end. Kill dosfsck, ret=-1
```

*Android 2.2*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved both problems:

1) Remove battery and reboot. Two times because it was still behaving strange the first time.

2) Remove files little by little, until I found the problematic file, called `%01.%02`, I recognized its content as a tile from the Maverick map app (which I have not launched so it is more of a random casualty). Anyway, I renamed that file to `a.a.` and then deletion was successful.